# Host multiple domains on a server that has single Static IP

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I want to host two domains on Windows Server 2003.
I already have a static IP and a domain running.

What DNS and IIS settings should I have for the later?

For example;
for www.abc.com and www.def.com I have created two primary zones on the DNS. I am using the same NS for both NS1.abc.com and NS2.abc.com

On IIS I created a new site www.def.com and used an unused internal (dummy IP)

NSLOOKUP gives me the IP of my "domain name provider's" ip (where I entered NS1.abc.com and NS1.abc.com for the www.def.com domain)

I hope I don't need another static IP for www.def.com domain 
Please advice.

Comment: For Host Header approach this link must be useful but as I commented to @joeqwerty  answer IIS doesn't support SSL with Host Headers.

Comment: The question doesn't make any mention of SSL. Why are you making such an adamant statement about it?

Comment: @joeqwerty I answerd your answer below the duplicate unkind comment of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS you can use host headers to host both web sites on the same ip address. Since you've only got a single public ip address you have to forward HTTP traffic from the single public ip address to a single internal ip address and host headers is how IIS differentiates between the two web sites.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324287

Comment: IIS doesn't support Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) with host headers!

Comment: The question doesn't make any mention of SSL. Why are you making such an adamant statement about it?

Comment: Yeah, the question has not anything about SSL, but nowadays SSL is so important things in the web app world. Please use the chrome and other web browser and you will see a hint about not secure in not SSL websites. Are you believe to keep darkness rather extending knowledge? I can't understand what you think and what is your means of writing this rough answer rather appreciate this clarifying.

Comment: This question is almost 8 years old. I answered the question as it was asked at the time that it was asked. I didn't say anything about anything else. It seems strange that you would attempt to brow beat me in such a manner.

Comment: I think you started with unkind words. Please read your comments again. I didn't try to beat you. I just had a question, I searched, reached this question and answer (no matter for 8 years ago or not), read all part carefully, I read other discussions and commented about the subject I thought may help others. What did I wrong in your opinion? If you don't know about the better solution you can just do nothing, Otherwise please share it. Anyway, I think this discussion is over. please forgot. Goodluck.